# How to get a slow/heavy scroll affect using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am trying to implement a scrolling effect into a website. The effect I am trying toachieve can be seen at

https://loirevalleylodges.com/
and
https://ceremonycoffee.com/

the closest thing I can get to this is using the code:

```
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

    handle(delta);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
    var time = 1000;
    var distance = 300;
    
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time );
}
```

However, this more feels like it gives the scroll momentum. I would like to slow down the page scroll or make it feel 'heavy'.

The site I am trying to implement this on is:

demo.simplerwebsites.com

any hints or tips to get me going in the right direction?